# How to set fk while insert row in SQL developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-xe

I use SQL Developer (with Oracle XE) to set 3 tables and add PK,FK.. now I want to add some rows...

```
INSERT INTO "ADMIN"."POST" (NAME_POST) VALUES ('asd')

ORA-02291: integrity constraint (ADMIN.POST_DEPARTMENT_FK1) violated - parent key not found
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

I don't know where I can find this `FK` to choose one! With SQL Developer, I only fill the columns without FK, so I need help to find how to do it right using `SQLDeveloper`.

---

New information:

I don't know why, but I have a one-to-one relation between DEPARTMENT and POST.

```
 CREATE TABLE "ADMIN"."POST" 
   (    "ID_POST" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME_POST" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "POST_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_POST")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "POST_DEPARTMENT_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_POST")
      REFERENCES "ADMIN"."DEPARTMENT" ("ID_DEPARTMENT") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;

  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "ADMIN"."POST_ID" 
BEFORE INSERT ON POST 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  if(:new.ID_POST is null) then
  SELECT S_POST.nextval
  INTO :new.ID_POST
  FROM dual;
  end if;
END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "ADMIN"."POST_ID" ENABLE;
```

Comment: You must insert a record with parent key first. This is how foreign keys works - a record cannot be inserted into the table when a value of the foreign key doesn't exist in the referenced table.

Comment: Excuse me, but that is not the point. I have some rows with Departments, so i have existed keys. But where i can find it while inserting? If i insert new data in Post table i dont see anything about fk.. its about "how to get fk column while inserting data in SQL Developer", its not about "what this error mean?" Thx.

Comment: Take a look at the examples here with the "returning" clause: http://psoug.org/reference/insert.html Insert into the master table, returning the pk into a variable. Then use that variable as part of the insert into the child table.  Or, if the record already exists in the master table, do a lookup first.

Comment: Is it mean that i cant do it with SQL Developer (i cant beliave it, oracles forsment). And i need to use something like sql plus? just console soluion?
P.S.: i just want to know about using this tool, even if i write a trigger i still dont know how to insert fk, becouse programm doesnt have column with fk to choose(

Comment: So your table DEPARTMENT contains all NAME_POSTs? And your table POST contains details for each NAME_POST? This is not really what I would have expected. I would have guessed DEPARTMENT contains departments identified maybe with DEPARTMENT_ID. And a child table would hold additional information on each DEPARTMENT_ID. Please think this over.

Comment: Moreover, you would add details in your child table. Why would you want to add details and not knowing details for what? You want to add details on 'asd', but 'asd' is not even in your system yet? And of course you can simply _select_ rows of your parent table to see the available keys.

Comment: No, damn. DEPARTMENT conatains idDep and nameDep - thats all. POST contain idPost and FK DEPARTMENT ID - yes, its child table. Yes, i know all my keys.. i dont see how to add rows in POST via that keys coz havent any input to do that.. mb u want to help, but u dont get the point.
I know how to do it with SQL transact. I have no idea how to do it with SQL Developer. Adding rows in child table - simple ha? but i see only columns without fk access.

Comment: SQL Developer is just a client, as is SQL*Plus. Not sure what you mean about not having input, but you said you know your keys. If you know the FK value I don't get what your issues is; what's wrong with `insert into post (name_post, idDep) values ('asd', your_dep_id_value)`? (I guess your `idPost` is being set from a sequence via a trigger?) Are you doing this in an SQL Worksheet or in a table view; maybe you opened the table view before you added the FK column and you need to refresh it to see the current structure?

Comment: usual table view in free version of SQLDev, inset "Data" - you can adding rows, but u see all columns exept fk. Im interested in visual solution, ofc Worksheet works fine. Yes i have triggers for ids.

Comment: oh god i realize it. Looks like i have fk in POST but SQL Dev thinks that i have one to one relation with DEPARTMENTS.. how it can be?

Comment: Sounds like you built your FK incorrectly; either your FK is linking the wrong field to the dept table, or your trigger is assigning the FK value (which would be wrong). Please add the table creation commands (plus any `alter` commands), and the trigger definitions. But it still sounds like you need to close and reopen the table view so it sees the FK column there - SQL Developer doesn't hide that, but it won't show it if the column was added after the window was opened.

Comment: This is example of trigger i used:
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "ADMIN"."DEPARTMENT_ID" 
BEFORE INSERT ON DEPARTMENT 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  if(:new.ID_DEPARTMENT is null) then
  SELECT SEQUENCE_DEPARTMENT.nextval
  INTO :new.ID_DEPARTMENT
  FROM dual;
  end if;
END;

Comment: Great, but it's the `post` table that has the issue. Please add new information by editing your question, not in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and post have FK CONSTRAINT "POST_DEPARTMENT_FK1" FOREIGN KEY
>   ("ID_POST") REFERENCES "ADMIN"."DEPARTMENT" ("ID_DEPARTMENT") ON
>   DELETE CASCADE ENABLE

Well, there's your problem. You've got a `id_post` field which is - hopefully - the primary key of the `post` table, and the trigger supports that. But you've also made *the same column* a foreign key to the department table. By doing that you have created the one-to-one relationship. That cannot work - the trigger is assigning a new `post_id` value from its sequence, and it would be mere fluke if the `department` table had a PK with the same value.

Assuming your `post` table also has a `id_department` column, the FK should be:

```
CONSTRAINT "POST_DEPARTMENT_FK1"
FOREIGN KEY ("ID_DEPARTMENT")
REFERENCES "ADMIN"."DEPARTMENT" ("ID_DEPARTMENT")
ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE
```

It sounds like you're also saying that SQL Developer isn't showing you the FK column, `department_id`, in the data editor. The only way I can see that being the case is if you opened the table view before you added that column via an `alter` command. The table view doesn't refresh automatically if the table definition changes. Close the table and re-open it, and you'll see the current structure, including the FK column.

---

OK, from your question edit, you do not have a column to hold the `department_id` that you want to be the FK. You need to include that column, and make it the FK:

```
CREATE TABLE "ADMIN"."POST" 
   (    "ID_POST" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME_POST" VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ID_DEPARTMENT" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT "POST_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_POST")
  USING INDEX ...
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "POST_DEPARTMENT_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("ID_DEPARTMENT")
      REFERENCES "ADMIN"."DEPARTMENT" ("ID_DEPARTMENT")
      ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE
   ) ...
  )
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;
```

Not a good idea to put your own objects in the `SYSTEM` tablespace though; create a new one for your `ADMIN` objects.

If you have no data yet it will be easiest to drop and recreate the table. Otherwise you can use `alter table` commands to add the column and drop and recreate the constraint.

Comment: indeed! Thx, now i got it. But SQL Developer not allow me to change it O_o ill add image of that.

Comment: Oh well u already fix it while i asking) SYSTEM - geneated code, idk how it generates still. But you doing a great job for me. Thx alot.

Comment: @Khronos - if you aren't specifying a tablespace when you create the table then it'll use your user's default tablespace. If you create a new tablespace, which I'd recommend, also alter the user to change the default, which will apply to indexes too. I guess the code you showed is the DDL it shows you, not what you actually typed, then? Thought it was a bit odd to have the storage specified...